# Taking columns of data copying and pasting them under eachother VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I know this is a real simple solution, but what I want to do is take column D14:E, and paste the numerical values into another part of the worksheet, the correct code is below:

```
Range("D14", Cells(Rows.Count, "E")).Copy
Range("AH14", Cells(Rows.Count, "AI").End(xlUp)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

My issue here is when I am trying to take a second set of columns and paste it underneath the one I just pasted. The code I am trying is below:

```
Range("N14", Cells(Rows.Count, "O")).Copy
Range("AH14" & Cells(Rows.Count, "AI").End(xlUp)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Note that the columns are varying sizes (meaning column D could be a different size because of previous variables that were inputted (I had a question that was answered previously if you want to know what I mean)).

Comment: What exactly is your question? What is LastRow?

Comment: Whoops, that wasn't supposed to be in the code. Ill fix it shortly essentially I was using what was in the the previous block.

Comment: My question is how do I copy values, from a column, and paste them in another column. then copy values from a different column, and pate them under the original pasted values. What I am trying to do here is make a chart from all the values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Range("N14", Cells(Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp)).Copy ' Copy columns
    Range("AH14").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select ' Find the first free column, select it
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues 'paste copied cells`